# Where to find object in SQL Server and determine if it's a view or table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having a problem that I think is easy to resolve but cant put my finger on it.

I did not create this database or jobs so troubleshooting my way through it.

I have a SQL Server job that is failing, it has multiple steps.

One of the steps is

```
select * into [Pastel_OrderStock] from [Pastel_SOProducts]
```

This fails with error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Now if I try and go:

```
select * from [Pastel_SOProducts]
```

it gives same error.

My issue is that I can't see a table or view `Pastel_SOProducts` in any of my database tables or views but it obviously exists given the error.

How can I find out where this is and more importantly view the table structure or view syntax?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name), type_desc FROM sys.objects WHERE name = N'Pastel_SOProducts';` and then, if it's a view, `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION([object_id]);`

Comment: P.S. this is one of the reasons you should always properly reference your objects with two-part names.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that returns a result of the table name. but how do I troubleshoot this or find out where the table is in my management studio console? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's a synonym? Maybe it's not in `dbo` so you're not spotting it alphabetically? Maybe you're looking in the wrong database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be in [`sys.objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx). The `type` and `type_desc` will show what object type is.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- Check your permission. Your DB administrator could have restricted your account to certain tables.
- Check the table's owner is not dbo.

Comment: A permission problem would not yield a conversion error. If they're allowed to select from the object to the point where they get an error, then there can't be a restriction preventing them from seeing that the object exists.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17533993/4089147) you want to pull the 'type_desc' from the sys.objects table:

```
select name, type, type_desc from sys.objects where name = 'Pastel_SOProducts'
```